# How to get the text from child nodes if it is parents to other node in Scrapy using XPath

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am facing a problem where I have to get the result from the child node which may or may not be parents to some other node using Xpath in scrapy. consider the case like

```
<h1 class="main">
 <span class="child">data</span>
</h1>
```

or

```
<h1 class="main">
<span class="child">
 <span class="child2">data</span>
</span>
</h1>
```

My solution was `response.xpath(".//h1[@class='main']/span/text()").extract()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `//text`, and it will return all text elements in a list from within your **span**, both parent and child:

```
response.xpath(".//h1[@class='main']/span//text()").extract()
```

Comment: @PramodBisht, if my answer helps you solve the issue. Please **accept** my answer / upvote :)

Comment: to upvote atleast 15 points are required and I am beginner with only one points. I hope you understand.

Comment: @PramodBisht, appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `response.xpath("string(.//h1[@class='main']/span)").extract()`
- or even `response.xpath("string(.//h1[@class='main'])").extract()` if you're after the whole header text