# Unable to get text from parent and child nodes/tags with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

before this is marked as duplicate, I've searched and tried other solutions found on SO, which are:

1. [scrapy css selector: get text of all inner tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985060/scrapy-css-selector-get-text-of-all-inner-tags/40985082)
2. [How to get the text from child nodes if it is parents to other node in Scrapy using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631196/how-to-get-the-text-from-child-nodes-if-it-is-parents-to-other-node-in-scrapy-us)
3. [scrapy get the entire text including children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564843/scrapy-get-the-entire-text-including-children)

The HTML I want to extract from is:

```
<span class="location">
    Mandarin Oriental Hotel
    <a class="" href="/search-results/Jalan+Pinang%252C+Kuala+Lumpur+City+Centre%252C+50088+Kuala+Lumpur%252C+Wilayah+Persekutuan./?state=Kuala+Lumpur" itemprop="addressRegion" title="Jalan Pinang, Kuala Lumpur City Centre, 50088 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan.">
    Jalan Pinang, Kuala Lumpur City Centre, 50088 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan.
    </a>
    ,
    <a class="" href="/search-results/?neighbourhood=Kuala+Lumpur&state=Kuala+Lumpur" title="Kuala Lumpur">
    Kuala Lumpur
    </a>
    ,
    <a class="" href="/search-results/?state=Kuala+Lumpur" title="Kuala Lumpur">
    Kuala Lumpur
    </a>
    <span class="" itemprop="postalCode">
        50088
    </span>
</span>
```

I want to get all the text in the //span[@class='location'] .

I have tried:

1. `response.xpath("//span[@class='location']//text()").extract_first()`
2. `response.css("span.location *::text").extract_first()`
3. `response.css("span.location ::text").extract_first()`

All of them only return `Mandarin Oriental Hotel`, not the full address.

EDIT:
The text should yield

> Mandarin Oriental Hotel Jalan Pinang, Kuala Lumpur City Centre, 50088 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan., Kuala Lumpur, Kuala Lumpur 50088

Comment: I'm not Scrapy user, but I guess this is because you're using `extract_first`. Try `"  ".join(response.xpath("//span[@class='location']//text()").extract())`

Comment: @Andersson That would yield addresses for all individual items in the page unfortunately. The page: https://www.hungrygowhere.my/search-results/?search_location=Kuala+Lumpur

Comment: You mean that it returns all the addresses as single string and you want separate address for each result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below code to get string representation of each `span` with address:

```
for entry in response.xpath("//div[@class='entry']"):
    print(entry.xpath("normalize-space(./span[@class='location'])").extract_first())
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I had to remove .extract() from the first line.

`for entry in response.xpath("//div[@class='entry']"):
    print(entry.xpath("normalize-space(./span[@class='location'])").extract_first())`

Comment: @AmirAsyraf , oh, right. Thanks for corrected me... Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

With `response.css("span.location ::text").extract_first()` you get only first text, so you can try to call `response.css("span.location ::text").extract()` and then concatenate it.

Also you can try get whole parent element and remove tags from it:

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

data = response.css('span.location').get()
if not data:
    return
result = remove_tags(data)
```

Comment: .extract() would get the full address, but it will also get all other addresses for every entry/item in the page. I want the full individual address for separate for each entry/item.